# getLastSignInTimestamp() and getCreationTimestamp() do not work properly

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was using the code below to check if the user is singing in for the first time. Everything was fine, but today I faced a weird bug. `getCreationTimestamp()` and `getLastSignInTimestamp` always return the same timestamp for all users. After some testings, I found out that these timestamps belong to one of the users. It does not matter who is signed in, the two methods always return the timestamps for that specific user!

```
FirebaseUserMetadata fbUserMetadata = fbUser.getMetadata();
if (fbUserMetadata.getCreationTimestamp() == fbUserMetadata.getLastSignInTimestamp()) // New user
```

Comment: Did you try signing out the user (using the Firebase Auth API to do so, not just quitting the app), then signing them back in to see if the last sign in time changes?

Comment: @DougStevenson It worked! Thank you so much!
Now, could you please clarify why does that happen?

Comment: That's just the way client listeners work.  It's by design.

Comment: But when I sign in with another user, why does everything update (name, email..etc) except the timestamps?!
Also, I just realized that when my application runs, getCurrentUser() is not null! So, does Firebase persists user authentication by default?

Comment: @DougStevenson: It returns same value in case of `AuthStateListener`. It is impractical to logout user every time he leaves the app. What is the best practice here?